# Setting up Sphinx Autodoc with existing project

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

I'm am completely new to Sphinx and have watched hours of tutorials, but could not find the answer to my issue

I have a current project structure like the following

```
-project folder
 |-sub folder 1
 | |- sub folder 1.a
 |    | - ...
 |-sub folder 2
 | |- sub folder 2.a
 |    | - ...
 |-sub folder 3
 | |- sub folder 3.a
 |    | - ...
 |- .py files
 |...
 |- conf.py
 |- index.rst
 |- Makefile
 |- _build/
 |  |-doctrees/
 |  |-html/
 |    |...(all the html files generated by "make html")
```

I have included the following in my conf.py

```
extensions = ['autoapi.extension']
# Document Python Code
autoapi_type = 'python'
autoapi_dir = '../project folder'
```

inside each of the sub folders i have .py files that contain classes, functions, modules, members that all need to be documented. Is there a way that sphinx will parse through the current project folder and all of its subdirectories in search for .py files to autodoc? If so, how would I have to set up my index.rst and conf.py file to make this happen?

The error I am seeing is as follows:

```
Removing everything under '_build'...
Running Sphinx v1.8.5  
making output directory...  

Extension error: 
You must configure an autoapi_dirs setting  
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'html' failed 
make: *** [html] Error 2
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? [`sphinx-apidoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) should pick up Python packages, which by definition must include `__init__.py` in each directory, and writes `.rst` source files. Then you run `make html` to build the HTML version of your docs.

Comment: @StevePiercy I added my error above. Thank you for your quick response!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explicit: `You must configure an autoapi_dirs setting`. You have a typo in your `conf.py` setting, omitting the "s" in your setting `autoapi_dir`. See configuration value of [`autoapi_dirs` for `autoapi`](https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-autoapi_dirs).

Comment: What do you mean by omitting the "s" ? Can you provide an explicit example using my conf.py setting above? Are you saying my "autoapi_dir" should actually be "autoapi_dirs"

Comment: That fixed that issue! Much appreciated!